How to Implement a Mixed Effect Model for Nested Data in R?

Data sample below.

I'm working on an analysis involving a complex nested dataset and I need to implement a mixed effect model in R. Here's a brief overview of my situation:

Objective: Determine the effect of personality traits (OCEAN),
emotional states, situational perception, and emotional perception on
the evaluation of valence of images generated by artificial
intelligence.
Problem: I've previously run regression models without    fully
accounting for the nested structure in the data. The regression
coefficients from these models are extremely small, and I'm not
confident in their accuracy.
Data Structure: The data is nested, with    images nested within
participants, and participants nested within surveys.

Data Details:

I conducted 60 surveys, each containing 20 different images, and
applied these surveys to 20 participants.
The surveys also include 5 additional images that are common across
all surveys.
For the analysis, my dataset is structured so that the first 20 rows
correspond to the first participant's reactions to the 20 images of
the survey. The next 20 rows correspond to the next participant, and
so on. The participant's personality and emotional states are
repeated 20 times, since they are constant for the same person. This
repetition is the repeated measures part, while the situational and
emotional perceptions vary.

Here is a sample of the data with not repeated images, in case the explanation of the data is unclear.
What I've Tried:

Separating the analysis of the 5 common images and the uncommon
images.
Analyzing each of the common images separately.
Computing the mean of the 5 common images to account for repeated
measures, reducing the data to one row per participant for these
images.
Running simpler regression models that only have the participant as a higher level.

Here is the code for the not repeated images:
# Define the formula for the model for valence
valence_formula <- as.formula(paste("valence ~ water + ground + mountain + tree + snow + O + C + E + A + N + angry + good + bad + happy + sad + nice + unfriendly + tense + relaxed + curiosity + rage + fear + sexy + careness + sadness + playfulness + work + intellectual + threat + romance + positive + negative + deceit + communication + (1 | survey_index/image_name)", collapse = " + "))

# Fit the regression model for valence using lmer
valence_model <- lmer(valence_formula, data = df)

Here is the code for the common images:
# Define the formula for the model for valence
valence_formula <- as.formula(paste("valence ~ water + ground + mountain + tree + O + C + E + A + N + angry + good + bad + happy + sad + nice + unfriendly + tense + relaxed + curiosity + rage + fear + sexy + careness + sadness + playfulness + work + intellectual + threat + romance + positive + negative + deceit + communication + (1 | image_name) + (1 | participant_id)", collapse = " + "))

# Fit the regression model for valence using lmer
valence_model <- lmer(valence_formula, data = df)

As you can see from the data, I recognize a nested design for the not repeated images model and a crossed design for the common images. More on that here.
Questions:

How can I properly implement a mixed effect model in R to account
for the nested structure of my data (images within participants
within surveys)?
What packages and functions should I use for this type of analysis?

Any guidance or example code snippets would be greatly appreciated!


How can I properly implement a mixed effect model in R to account for the nested structure of my data (images within participants within surveys)?

In the random part of the formula you would have something like:
... + (1|survey/participant/image)

Before using this formula, you should verify that you have coded these factors appropriately. See my answer to this question for details of this.

What packages and functions should I use for this type of analysis?

In R you have several options. You seem to be familiar with lmer from the lme4 package, so that would be a reasonable place to start, although since you appear to have repeated measures you may need to explicitly model the residual covariance structure. lme4 does not provide this, but you can sometimes get away with including the "time" variable as a random slope. If you decide to be more explicit and specify, for example, an autoregressive structure (AR1 is by far the most common), then you would have to look elsewhere - nlme, glmmTMB, GLMMadaptive and mmrm are possibilities.
You might find the following thread useful:
Beyond AR(1) as a covariance structure for mixed models with repeated measures
Finally, I noticed this bullet point in the question:

Computing the mean of the 5 common images to account for repeated measures, reducing the data to one row per participant for these images.

This is rarely a good idea. You are throwing away important data by taking averages instead of making full use of the data.
I can highly recommend the free online course "Statistical Analysis of Repeated Measurements Data" by Dimitris Rizopoulos (the author of the GLMMadaptive package) who is quite often active here and always makes excellent contributions (answers):
https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/219012/dimitris-rizopoulos?tab=profile
https://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/CE08.pdf
